# How to access the Tools / Menu / Settings in on a Chromecast?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

Ive got a 4k Chromecast connected via an HDMI Matrix (kind of like a  splitter) to 2 TVs. I use the Chromecast to mirror a Chromebook to the TVs.

Im having a couple of issues with the Chromecast though (see below) in principal i think id be able to fix both of these issue pretty easily but i cant find out how to access the Menu / Tools of the Chromecast. It seems you used to be able to do this via a Chrome browser plugin [(info here)](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-change-the-time-on-your-chromecast-device/), but this has since been dis continued. Any ideas how to access the Tools / Menu now ?

Issues : 
- Time on Chromecast screensaver is wrong
- Chromecast crops the mirrored image on the screen, on Apple TV this can be fixed by changing the overscan settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Page: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6398952?hl=en

Google removed all these Options.

Cite: "In previous versions of the Cast button, you could set options for resolution, bitrate, quality, etc. when mirroring the contents of your tab to your Chromecast device.  These options have been removed, as the system now automatically adjusts quality, frame rate and resolution based upon your content and the quality of your network."

You should still be able to set the Timezone via the Android/iOS Control App newly called Google Home previous called Chromecast (at least on iOS this is the case)

Comment: Thanks, ive managed to update the time via the 'Google Home' iOS app. Shame about the frame rate, resolution etc. not being manually editable though as their automatic settings just dont cut it.